# My forum search cant be more than just search subject

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on my thesis and i'm trying to make a standart forum,
but I'm having a problem with my search.

Right now it's only searching my thread subject instead of searching the text in that thread.

```
`$query=mysql_db_query($db,"SELECT topic,isi FROM forum where ID_replay=0 and topic like '%$key%' or isi like '%key%' order by date desc",$koneksi);`
```

It seems that the query is only searching from the "topic" columns in that table forum. I'm using `ID_replay` to order my result by by date, so i'm confused on why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to group your conditions...

```
SELECT topic,isi 
FROM   forum 
where  ID_replay = 0 AND
       (topic LIKE '%$key%' OR isi LIKE '%key%') 
ORDER  BY date DESC
```

Comment: Great its work, but why it cant search few word. its only search word that close to it. ex: "i know it will true" if i search "i know it" result show, but if i try " i know true" it result no data??

Comment: because the string `i know it will true` does not contain a word `know` the is followed by `true`. you can search for `FULL TEXT SEARCH` on this